# My 18V 10 watt solar panel

Tags: power-supply, power

I have a Huawei internet router with 12 volt 2 ampere input power.  I bought a solar panel 18V 10 watt with direct connection plug which I'm to use for the router but it seem to not working.

[image: My SOLAR PANEL]

Please I need solution on how to make this to device work because I'm using this where there is AC power at all typically sun base device is what is needed there, I thought of connecting the 12 volt adapter direct to the panel then to router but I don't just know how well it will work.

Comment: The (12 Volts 2 Amps) INPUT power of the Router i want to power with the Solar panel

Comment: Please i think i have made my self clear

Comment: Please add specifications of your solar panel or add a picture of it.

Comment: 12v, 2 amps is 24 watts. Your solar panels only output 10 watts. Your solar panel is too small by more than half.

Comment: ok, can i use 18V 20watt solar panel power it? because that's the next and only option available at the moment

Comment: Two things would help. First, what is the AVERAGE current you need to run your HUAWEI device. Second, are you able to add a battery to the system, or you want to use solar panel only?

Comment: @mkeith I Couldn't add battery to it because of the solar construction so i want to use only solar panel

Comment: @mkeith i need 12 volt 2amps to run the HUAWEI device

Comment: @RonBeyer Well, the router probably doesn't use 2 amps all the time. That's just the rated maximum. LazBorn could measure how much current it *actually* uses, or just hope and pray.

Answer (score 2):

Since we don't really know how much power the router needs on average, it is hard to size the panels. The 2A rating is most likely the maximum that is required, not the average. So my suggestion is to use two of the 20W panels in parallel.

You will also need some type of voltage regulator to protect the router from over-voltage.

Please note that the router will only function when bright sun is shining on the panels. If there are clouds, or shade from trees, or if the sun is low in the sky, the router will not function.

Also, under some conditions when there is not enough sun, the router may reboot over and over. Not sure if this could damage the router or cause other problems. This is kind of a complex problem to solve so I am not going to get into it. Just be aware that this might happen.

Comment: Just want to add that the simplest voltage regulator in this setup would be a 12V battery in parallel, no matter how small. The battery will prevent the voltage from spiking. As well as preventing power loss during a cloudy day.

Comment: @NatsuKage I agree that a battery would simplify things in some ways. However, it may not be enough by itself to regulate voltage. A charge controller would still be recommended to make sure the battery does not get over-charged.

Comment: As i dont really mind the power lost as you mention @Natsu Kage, if it can supply  power whenever it gets energy am ok with that as the device will be use on for CCTV view meanwhile the router has small inbuilt battery on its own.

Comment: I see. If you have an internal battery already, then I suggest you install a regulator circuit. The most cost effective would be a small LM2596 DC to DC Buck Converter circuit. This will prevent spikes and still charge correctly your Router.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 18v, 20 watt solar panel to power your router. Just make sure it doesn’t go cloudy or your internet will cut out. I recommend a battery backup.

You cannot directly connect your 18v to your 12v input either. You need an adaptor in between. I am assuming dc. Look for a 12v dc-dc convertor like this one: 
[https://www.amazon.com/Ultra-MP1584EN-Converter-Adjustable-Module/dp/B07SJFTD7F/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07SJFTD7F)

If you choose another one pay attention to efficiency and power rating. Plug your solar panel positive and negative leads to the input side and plug the positive and negative leads from the router to the output side. Make sure you have adjusted the little potentiometer to get a 12v output if you use an adjustable regulator.

Comment: Just a couple of observations. A 20 Watt solar panel puts out 20 Watts under standard test conditions. Under real world conditions it will put out substantially less power. The two main variables are panel temperature and illumination. As the panel temperature goes up, the panel puts out less power. As the amount of sun hitting the panel is reduced, the power is reduced. Also note that the nominal rating of the 12V adaptor is 24Watts. For this reason, a single 20W panel is unlikely to be the best solution, although it may work under optimal conditions.

Comment: @mkeith your observation is correct but now is't that this particular panel won't work for the purpose or that i must get a 12v dc converter

Comment: It is not enough power. I would use two panels in parallel.

Comment: @mkeith I agree. Derating power is always a good idea for critical applications.